# how can I remove some rows that are partial duplicates in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame but it has many overlapping rows. However, I cannot erase it because not all values are equal.
data consists of 5 * 18000000 values.

```
date     station_number    station   latitude   longitude
0101      11428            hansung      0         127.5
0101      11428            hansung      0         127.7
0101      11374           bookmuseum    0         127.3
0101      11380            mokryeon     14        127.9
0101      11380            mokryeon     14        128.1
0101      11388            healthcent   86        126.1
```

I want to erase row number 2 and row number 5 and all the other rows that have same date, station_number and station name. Or I want to unify rows of same values anyway. I need your help.

Comment: The title of your post is not very informative and does not describe well the problem... Maybe you could mention the rows are _partial duplicates_ instead of _overlapping_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove rows with `duplicated` values across multiple columns like this:

```r
df [!duplicated(df[c(1:3)]),]
#>   date station_number    station latitude longitude
#> 1  101          11428    hansung        0     127.5
#> 3  101          11374 bookmuseum        0     127.3
#> 4  101          11380   mokryeon       14     127.9
#> 6  101          11388 healthcent       86     126.1

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  distinct(date, station_number, station, .keep_all = TRUE)
#>   date station_number    station latitude longitude
#> 1  101          11428    hansung        0     127.5
#> 2  101          11374 bookmuseum        0     127.3
#> 3  101          11380   mokryeon       14     127.9
#> 4  101          11388 healthcent       86     126.1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 'date     station_number    station   latitude   longitude
0101      11428            hansung      0         127.5
0101      11428            hansung      0         127.7
0101      11374           bookmuseum    0         127.3
0101      11380            mokryeon     14        127.9
0101      11380            mokryeon     14        128.1
0101      11388            healthcent   86        126.1', header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some arbitrariness in your deletion rule, since some rows are identical on some columns but nor others. I would recommend using `groups_by(same_columns) %>% slice_*()`, where you can choose between `slice_min()`, `slice_head()` etc, which will make your rule explicit.

Using this, you will realize that the solution given by @Quinten, with `distinct(date, station_number, station, .keep_all = TRUE)`, corresponds to using `slice_head(n=1)`, that is take the first row of duplicates. But you could also choose, to take the last `slice_tail(n=1)`, or the one where `longitude` is highest (`slice_max(longitude)`), etc.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- read.table(text = 'date     station_number    station   latitude   longitude
0101      11428            hansung      0         127.5
0101      11428            hansung      0         127.7
0101      11374           bookmuseum    0         127.3
0101      11380            mokryeon     14        127.9
0101      11380            mokryeon     14        128.1
0101      11388            healthcent   86        126.1', header = TRUE)

df %>%
  group_by(date, station_number, station) %>% 
  slice_min(longitude) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>    date station_number station    latitude longitude
#>   <int>          <int> <chr>         <int>     <dbl>
#> 1   101          11374 bookmuseum        0      127.
#> 2   101          11380 mokryeon         14      128.
#> 3   101          11388 healthcent       86      126.
#> 4   101          11428 hansung           0      128.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>